# Delete all of a file except for certain words that contain certain letters

Tags: command-line, search, regular-expression

I have a file that contains words that I want to save, along with other junk that I do not need.  I just want to delete everything except the words that contain a certain pattern. Take email addresses for example:

`foo foo foo foo foo foo@foo.com
foo foo foo2@foo2.net`

Run some magic and save everything from `@` to the previous and next `space`.

`foo@foo.com foo2@foo2.net`

This would be useful in so many applications (especially email addresses).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Easy way - `grep`

The easiest technique is to use `:%!grep -o {pat}`. The `-o`/`--only-matching` make grep only display the matches.

```
:%!grep -o 'foo\w*bar'
```

Note: that grep's regex's are a different variant from PCRE and Vim's.

#### Pure Vim method with plugin - still easy

For a pure native vim solution I suggest you look at [ExtractMatches](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4795) or [Yankitute](https://github.com/idanarye/vim-yankitute) plugins.

#### (Ab)Using `:s` for fun and profit

You want to roll your "extract matches" command with `:s` with a sub-replace-expression (`\=`) and a list.

```
let lst = []
:%s/pattern/\=add(lst, submatch(0))[-1]/g
:%d
:pu=lst
:1d
```

The basic idea is to add each match to the list, `lst`, using a sub-replace-expression for the `:s` command. We can use some in-place array trickery to make sure the text doesn't change by always returning the last element of the array (what we just added).

This `:s` trick is often done in the form:

```
:let lst = []
:%s//\=add(lst, submatch(0))[-1]/g
:call setreg('"', join(lst, "\n"), 'l')
```

This will capture the current matches (uses last used pattern) into the default register. If you have Vim 7.4 then the `:s` can be simplified further: `:%s//\=add(lst, submatch(0))/gn`

#### More information

```
:h :range!
:h :s
:h sub-replace-expression
:h List
:h add()
:h submatch()
:h :d
:h :pu
:h @=
```

Comment: Wow!  Who would have thought that that would be so difficult in vim natively?  I really like the grep solution though.  Thanks!

Comment: Most of the hard work is done in the `:s` command. It is actually a testament to the versatility of the `:s` command. However it does pale in comparison to how easy this job is with `grep`.

Comment: This tip can do more than grep (which is line based) - delete all non-matching paragraphs in vim. E.g collect all multi-line functions in script:  :%s/^function\_.{-}endfunc/\\=add(lst,submatch(0))[-1]/gn, NOTE the last /n option - don't modify buffer during substition. Later paste lst as above.

Answer (score 4):

An applied answer (pure vim stuff) that keeps email addresses only:

```
:%s/\S\+@\S\+/\r\0\r/g
:v//d
```

1. place `\r` (carriage return, `CR`) before and after each email address (i.e. .break lines around each email found, so that each address will go on a separate line);
2. remove all lines which are *not* email addresses (last search pattern is used).

*Less specific usage*: change `\S\+@\S\+` with the desired `pattern`.

Comment: This is a better pure Vim way. However if you want to save the matches register without destroying the buffer, then the `:s` with sub-replace-expression is the way to go.

Comment: No doubt! It just seemed like a nice challenge.