# How to redirect search results into a new file?

Tags: regular-expression, search

Let's say, I want to search for email addresses and output them to a new file. What I can do so far with a help from another discussion is this:

```
g/pattern/.w! >> output.txt
```

but that saves whole lines where search matches occur. Is it possible to extract just the matches (with possibility for them to be multiple on one line)? I would prefer a solution (if possible) without some additional plugins or macros.

Comment: Related post: [Delete all of a file except for certain words that contain certain letters](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3869/778)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit easier with `grep` and the `--only-matching`/`-o` option.

```
grep -o 'pattern' file.txt > output.txt
```

You can use Vim's substitution as well:

```
:%s/.*\(pattern\).*/\1
```

This approach will affect the current buffer though. It would probably be best to copy the file first.

Note: these approachs assumes only 1 match per line

Answer (score 2):

Peter's solution with `grep -o` is the way to go IMO.

Yet, for the sake of the exercise here is a 100% pure vim script solution

```
" prepare the result variable to be of the right type
:let res = []
" join all lines in a big string, and use `substitute` to fill the result with matches -- this is the only tricky part
:call substitute(join(getline(1,'$'), ' '), 'THE PATTERN', '\=add(res, submatch(0))', 'g')

" You can remove duplicates BTW with
:let res = uniq(sort(res))

" And save into a new file
:call writefile(res, 'FILENAME')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you in Windows and don't have an access to bash commands and want to do it from VIM in any case.

g/.*Low rates.*/-1,+2.w! >> failures.txt

Will find all lines with the pattern .*Low rates.*
Copy 1 line before the pattern, 2 lines after, and redirect all occurrences of the pattern to a file failures.txt.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think you may have misunderstood the question; the OP wants to keep only the parts of the line that match the pattern. And a pure-vim solution has been provided.